# C++ DirectX 9 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, 64-bit, directx

Yes I included all the libs but every time I run my program in x64 it gives me an unresolved symbol but works perfectly in x32??

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol Direct3DCreate9Ex referenced in function "int **cdecl DirectXInit(struct HWND** *)" (?DirectXInit@@YAHPEAUHWND__@@@Z)    DirectX Overlay D:\VSprojects\2020\Mygui\Garrysmod take 2\Overlay aimbot\DirectX.obj    1

#### Source

```
    int DirectXInit(HWND hWnd)
    {
        if (FAILED(Direct3DCreate9Ex(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &p_Object)))
            exit(1);

        ZeroMemory(&p_Params, sizeof(p_Params));
        p_Params.Windowed = TRUE;
        p_Params.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        p_Params.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
        p_Params.MultiSampleQuality = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
        p_Params.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
        p_Params.BackBufferWidth = Width;
        p_Params.BackBufferHeight = Height;
        p_Params.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
        p_Params.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

        if (FAILED(p_Object->CreateDeviceEx(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &p_Params, 0, &p_Device)))
            exit(1);

        return 0;
    }





    char playerO[350] = { 0 };
    char enemyO[300] = { 0 };
    char aimbotO[300] = { 0 };
    char rect[300] = { 0 };
    int counter = 15;

    int Render()
    {


            p_Device->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0, 1.0f, 0);
            p_Device->BeginScene();


            //Drawing Stuff

            DrawBorderBox(10, 10, 200, 200, 15, 255, 255, 0, 0);


            p_Device->EndScene();
            p_Device->PresentEx(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return 0;

    }
```

#### Header

```
 #ifndef DIRECTX_H
#define DIRECTX_H


#include "Main.h"
#include "Drawings.h"
#include "read.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")


#include <dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")


extern IDirect3D9Ex* p_Object;
extern IDirect3DDevice9Ex* p_Device;
extern D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS p_Params;
extern ID3DXLine* p_Line;
extern ID3DXFont* pFontSmall;

extern RECT rc;

int DirectXInit(HWND hWnd);
int Render();

#endif
```

Again, it is most likely not do to with an include because it works like a clock in x32.

Comment: Looks like you have not linked to `d3d9.lib` static library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the legacy DirectX SDK, you have to set up distinct x86 vs. x64 library include paths:

In VC++ Directories for 32-bit configurations:

```
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
```

In VC++ Directories for 64-bit configurations:

```
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-)

> For new projects you should be using Direct3D 11, and you *do not* need to use the legacy DirectX SDK at all.

Answer (score 0):

x32 and x64 have different project configurations because you may need to point them to different library locations for each architecture. Double check to make sure that when you select x64 that the library and include directories still point to your DirectX include and libs folder.

You also need to make sure that under your includes

```
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
```

You have

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
```

Comment: Yeah they do have the same same include dir but both are under programfiles x86
Not sure, I would assume that it's the same and would work w x64
Dont think its that

Comment: @Blue_Ball_Paul what are your includes and are you linking to the dx9 libs with `#pragma comment`?

Comment: Is there a separate directx x64 sdk I need?

Comment: #include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

Comment: Can you edit your original post code to include the entire cpp file with the imports please